# Java: Consoled Multithreaded chat program

Tags: java, multithreading

This is a simple multithreaded chat program I'm doing. Everything works fine except the output formattting. AFter the client connects to the server, then the chat initiates. But on both the consoles, the message is prefixed with "Server: " instead of "Server: " for Client console and "Client: " for Server console (as per code)

**SERVER CODE**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

class Server
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(1234);
        Socket comsocket = ss.accept();

        BufferedReader fromClientConsole = new BufferedReader(new
                InputStreamReader(comsocket.getInputStream()));
        DataOutputStream outStream = new DataOutputStream(comsocket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader fromThisConsole = new BufferedReader(new
                InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.println("Starting Chat session... Type 'endchat' to end the chat");

        Thread read = new Thread(new Read(fromClientConsole));
        Thread write = new Thread(new Write(fromThisConsole, outStream));


        read.start();
        write.start();

        while( read.isAlive() || write.isAlive() ) ;

        comsocket.close();
        ss.close();
    }
}

class Read implements Runnable
{
    BufferedReader fromClientConsole = null;
    String message = "";
    Read(BufferedReader fromClientConsole)
    {
        this.fromClientConsole = fromClientConsole;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try{
            while(true)
            {
                message = fromClientConsole.readLine();
                System.out.println(message);
                if(message.equalsIgnoreCase("endchat")) break;
            }
        }

        catch(IOException e) { }
    }
}


class Write implements Runnable
{
    BufferedReader fromThisConsole=null;
    DataOutputStream outStream = null;
    String message = " ";
    Write(BufferedReader fromThisConsole, DataOutputStream outStream)
    {
        this.fromThisConsole = fromThisConsole;
        this.outStream = outStream;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try {
            while(true)
            {
                message = fromThisConsole.readLine();
                message = "Server: "+ message;
                outStream.writeBytes(message + "\n");
                if(message.equalsIgnoreCase("endchat")) break;
            }
        }

        catch(IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

**CLIENT CODE**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;


class Client
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        Socket connection_socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1234);
        DataOutputStream outStream = new
                DataOutputStream(connection_socket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader fromThisConsole = new BufferedReader(new
                InputStreamReader(System.in));
        BufferedReader fromServerConsole = new BufferedReader(new
                InputStreamReader(connection_socket.getInputStream()));

        System.out.println("Starting Chat session... Type 'endchat' to end the chat");

        Thread write = new Thread(new Write(fromThisConsole, outStream));
        Thread read = new Thread(new Read(fromServerConsole));

        write.start();
        read.start();

        while( write.isAlive() || read.isAlive() ) ;

        connection_socket.close();
    }
}

class Read implements Runnable
{
    BufferedReader fromServerConsole = null;
    String message = " ";
    Read(BufferedReader fromServerConsole)
    {
        this.fromServerConsole = fromServerConsole;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try{
            while(true)
            {
                message = fromServerConsole.readLine();
                System.out.println(message);
                if(message.equalsIgnoreCase("endchat")) break;
            }
        }

        catch(IOException e) {
        }
    }
}


class Write implements Runnable
{
    BufferedReader fromThisConsole = null;
    DataOutputStream outStream = null;
    String message = " ";
    Write(BufferedReader fromThisConsole, DataOutputStream outStream)
    {
        this.fromThisConsole = fromThisConsole;
        this.outStream = outStream;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try{
            while(true)
            {
                message = fromThisConsole.readLine();
                message = "Client: " + message;
                outStream.writeBytes(message + "\n");
                if(message.equalsIgnoreCase("endchat")) break;
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

Also, any suggestions or optimizations for this code are greatly accepted.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Are you actually running the Client class on the client??

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for a code review.

Answer (score 0):

Small tip: remove active waiting:

```
while( write.isAlive() || read.isAlive() ) ;
```

This keeps CPU running doing nothing useful. Better to use join here which use blocking:

```
write.join;
read.join;
```